# Concatenating .txt files using bash

Tags: linux, bash, report, concatenation

I want to make a report which is the concatenation of several .txt files. I wrote this bash code (~/scripts/report.sh)

```
echo "Display content of files in /etc/ directory"
for file in $(find ~/Research/reports/August/ -name '*.txt' -type f) ;
do
    echo "############START OF FILE#########"
    echo ${file}
    echo " "
    cat ${file}
    echo "##########END OF FILE########"
    echo " "
done
```

but I get the error:

```
'home/vdonchev/scripts/report.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `
'home/vdonchev/scripts/report.sh: line 2: `for file in $(find ~/Research/reports/August/ -name '*.txt' -type f) ;
```

I don't understand what is wrong: when I call only

```
find ~/Research/reports/August/ -name '*.txt' -type f
```

it works and indeed lists my .txt files.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I actually took the code from here: http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/204319-recursively-cat-files-directory-filename-printed-first.html

Comment: I tried running the code on Ubuntu 14 in Bash shell, changed `~/Research/reports/August/` to `/home/campovski/` and it worked...

Comment: I tried running the code on macOS, changed the directory to `~/Desktop` and it worked. From the log, it seems that there is a `\`` in your script but there is seems none in the script you posted

Comment: @campovski thanks you can see my answer.

Comment: Skip the loop and use `find ~/Research/reports/August/ -name '*.txt' -type f -printf '############START OF FILE#########\n%p\n\n' -exec cat {} \; -printf '##########END OF FILE########\n'`

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue. It seems that because I am opening my script through Windows some encoding gets disturbed.

After executing

```
dos2unix ~/scripts/report.sh
```

it worked like a charm :)

I hope I explained correctly.

Comment: Then you shouldn't tag `linux`

Comment: I work under Linux, but I have also Windows with a mapped network drive to the linux.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
for filename in ~/Research/reports/August/*.txt; do
```

Comment: That is different because it only goes through `.txt` files directly in `~/Research/reports/August/`, not in subdirectories...

Answer (score 0):

For me,

```
#/bin/sh

for file in $(find /path/to/repertory -name "*.txt" -type f)
do
   echo "############START OF FILE#########"
   cat $file
   echo "##########END OF FILE########"
done
```

did the trick. Then you should just launch like this :

```
 ./script.sh > concat.txt
```